# Copying code from Google Chrome View source includes line numbers

Tags: google-chrome

How do I copy code from Google Chrome's view source without including the line numbers?

Comment: Can't reproduce this issue in my Chrome ?

Comment: @cept0 likewise, Windows or Ubuntu.

Comment: I'm seeing this issue in OS X Canary, but **not** in 28.0.1500.95. If you're using Canary, maybe try the latest stable version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a known bug https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=269153

If you're using Canary, or the latest Chromium, try using Chrome stable (~28).